# Cache videos in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset

I want to cache videos that are displayed in a tableview. However, I am not sure what to cache. I'm using `AVFoundation`, in particular I'm using `AVPlayer` and creating `AVPlayerItem`'s.

My question is: what do I cache? Is it the `AVPlayer`, `AVPlayerItem`, or the underlying asset of `AVPlayerItem` called the `AVAsset`?

Please give a code sample (or library) with answer. Thanks!

Comment: Are you downloading the video from the web? i.e AVPlayer url, what its string? if I'm not mistaking you should download the video and store it in library document -for example- and then get its url

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, I am downloading all videos from the web. I am using this library which is a simple wrapper around the `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` classes called Vimeo `VIMVideoPlayer`. So yeah the library creates a `AVPlayer` and uses `AVPlayerItem` which are initialized with urls. Here is a sample video url: `https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/08C49094-DFB4-46DF-8110-EEEC7D4D6115-1133-000000B8AD9BE72C_1.0.1.mp4`.

What do you mean by: "should download the video and store it in library document" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `private var mediaCache = NSMutableDictionary()` for caching videos.

How to cache:

```
let assetForCache = AVAsset(url: URL(string: cell.videoRef)!)
self.mediaCache.setObject(assetForCache, forKey: cacheKey as NSCopying)
```

How to use: Just check if object exists in cache for this row. If yes - use it, no - download it

Answer (score 0):

Cache means download the video of each cell and try to use downloaded video for the second time . Either you can Temp location or Document directory. 
Execute a download call to download the video from URL [Video Link](https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/08C49094-DFB4-46DF-811%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0-EEEC7D4D6115-1133-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B000000B8AD9BE72C_1.0%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B.1.mp4).

In your cellForRowat indexpath check whether video available in your local if its there play.or else stream for the first time , simultaneously place a download 
call for that video in background .So that for second time you can use local video and play without internet .

Comment: Thanks for explanation. However I'm not sure what to cache as mentioned above, I know it's the video but with `AVFoundation`, would that be the `AVPlayer`, `AVPlayerItem`, or the underlying asset of `AVPlayerItem` called the `AVAsset`?